# Ruby Regex Evaluation only works once

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm designing a tool in ruby to parse data from a file based on provided regex mappings. I've designed a regex for parsing table declaration statements like these:

```
 Employees(INTEGER ID UNIQUE AUTOINCREMENT, TEXT NAME, TEXT POSITION);
 Sales(INTEGER ID, INTEGER EMP_ID, REAL MONEY, TEXT DATE);
```

When I attempt to parse a file containing this data using the regex and the method provided below, it only seems to parse the data for the Employees table, and not the Sales table. Furthermore, if I add a line between Employees and Sales like so, it will get stuck at the ***matchdata = regex.match line*** line:

```
Employees(INTEGER ID UNIQUE AUTOINCREMENT, TEXT NAME, TEXT POSITION);
Customers(INTEGER ID UNIQUE AUTOINCREMENT, TEXT NAME, TEXT DATA, TEXT PURCHASE_ID);
Sales(INTEGER ID, INTEGER EMP_ID, REAL MONEY, TEXT DATE);
```

Here is the regex in question:

```
(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\((?<parameters>(?:[\s,]*[a-zA-Z]+\s*)+)(?:\);)
```

Here is my test program:

```
require_relative '../main/regex_data_parser.rb'

parser = RegexParser.new
parser.add_regex('Sqlite_Table', /(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\((?<parameters>(?:[\s,]*[a-zA-Z]+\s*)+)(?:\);)/)
ddl_file = ARGV[0]
if ddl_file.length < 1 then
  puts 'No Input File provided.'
else
  parser.parse_file ddl_file
  parser.print_debug
end
```

And here is the method I'm using to parse the data (called from RegexParser):

```
#Parses file for data based on the provided regex.
def parse_file(file)
  #Exit the method with an error code of -1 if the regex is null
  if @regex_mappings.nil? || @regex_mappings.empty? then
    return -1
  end

  #Traverses the file, scanning for data
  @data_mappings = {}
  File.foreach(file) do |line|
    puts 'Scanning: ' + line
    #Assembles matchdata
    @regex_mappings.each do |obj_name, regex|
      puts 'Assembling matchdata for ' + obj_name
      matchdata = regex.match line  
      puts 'Matchdata assembled'
      if !matchdata.nil? then
        puts 'Found match data. Finding names of captured groups.'
        #Retrieves names of matched capture groups
        keys = matchdata.names
         if !keys.nil? then
           puts 'Found matched groups. Finding attributes'
           #Initializes mappings for this key
           if !@data_mappings.key? obj_name then
             puts 'Initialize object array: ' + obj_name
             @data_mappings[obj_name] = []
           end

           #Initializes the line data array
           line_data = []
           keys.each do |key|
             #Finds the value of each matched capture group on this line.
             value = matchdata[key]
             #Adds the mapping to the line data array
             line_data << [key, value]
           end

           #Maps the line data to the name of the regex being used
           @data_mappings[obj_name] << line_data
        end
      end
    end
  end

  return 0
end
```

I'd like to be able to parse each line based on the provided regex with named capture groups, and store the data relative to the assigned name of the regex. For this example, there should be a hash table with an entry for the key 'Sqlite_Table', which contains an array of subarrays. These subarrays represent the data objects being parsed from the file, and they are full of tuple arrays containing the name of the captured group and the captured value (these tuples represent object attributes).

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use two spaces for indenting Ruby code, not more/less/tabs etc

Comment: The underscore is missing in your character class. As an aside using the quantifier `{1}` is useless, remove them. `,` and `;` are not special characters, you don't need to escape them.

Comment: I've trimmed out the extra quantifiers/escape slashes. 

I'll also keep the two space indenting rule in mind.

Comment: Casimir, the underscore is exactly what was missing. Can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnRiley - Even if you add an underscore, you will still have the same problem when it encounters a partial form. It will either hang or come back after a long time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the fact that this expression `(?:[\s,]*[a-zA-Z]+\s*)+`
is too complex for the engine. There are too many backtracking paths.

If you change it to `(?:[\s,]*[a-zA-Z]\s*)+` it would work.

But, the only thing that is doing is insuring that there is at least  one
alpha character, it does not enforce any form with the comma.

If you don't care about alpha or comma you can use this.

```
 # (?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\((?<parameters>[a-zA-Z\s,]+)\)\;

 (?<name> [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ )      # (1)
 \(
 (?<parameters>                # (2 start)
      [a-zA-Z\s,]+ 
 )                             # (2 end)
 \)\;
```

However, if you do care about form, where you want at least an alpha
between commas, you could use a modified *unrolled loop* method like this

```
 # (?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\((?<parameters>(?:\s*[a-zA-Z])+(?:,(?:\s*[a-zA-Z])+)*\s*)\)\;

 (?<name> [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ )      # (1)
 \(
 (?<parameters>                # (2 start)
      (?:
           \s* 
           [a-zA-Z] 
      )+
      (?:
           ,
           (?:
                \s* 
                [a-zA-Z] 
           )+
      )*
      \s* 
 )                             # (2 end)
 \)\;
```